For a given experiment, $O_1, O_2,...$, is a sequence of outcomes, verify that $ P(O_i)=(\frac 12)^i,$ for $i = 1, 2,...$ is a probability measure.
If, for a given experiment, $O_1, O_2, O_3, ...$, is an infinite sequence of outcomes, verify that $P(O_i)=(\frac 12)^i,$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, ...$
is, indeed, a probability measure.
I tried solving this problem as follows:
We know that,
A probability measure must satisfy the following probability postulates for a discrete sample space $S$ :
POSTULATE 1 The probability of an event is a nonnegative real number; that is, $P(A)\geq 0$ for any subset $A $ of $S.$
POSTULATE 2 $P(S) = 1.$
POSTULATE 3 If $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$, is a finite or infinite sequence of mutually exclusive events of $S,$ then $P(A_1 ∪ A_2 ∪ A_3 ∪···) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + P(A_3) +···$
So, $P$ in ghe given problem will be a probability measure if the $3$ postulates above are satisfied.
We see that, $P(O_i)=\frac{1}{2^i}\geq 0,\forall i\in\Bbb N$ and thus, postulate 1 is satisfied.
Next, we note that, if $S$ is the sample space then $S=\{O_1,O_2,...\}.$
Each sample point of $S$ is mutually exclusive with all other sample points in $S.$ Thus, $P(S)=P(O_1)+P(O_2)+P(O_3)+...=1$ (using postulate $3$).
Hence, postulate $2$ is verified as well.
So, $P$ is indeed a probability measure if Postulate $3$ holds (, which we have indeed assumed in this solution).

However, I am not sure whether my solution is correct. This is mainly because of the $2$ reasons below:

I was asked to verify that $P$ is a probability measure. I was able to verify Postulate $1.$ For Postulate $2,$ as can be seen, I had to assume the validity of Postulate $3$ in order to verify that Postulate $2$ holds as well. But without assuming the validity of Postulate $3$ I doubt whether we could at all verify Postulate $2.$

Finally, I also assumed that the sample points in a sample space are mutually exclusive with respect to each other, i.e in other words, no two distinct event $\{O_i\}$ and $\{O_j\}$ (, where $i\neq j$) can't occur simultaneously. Can I always make this assumptions while solving probability problems? Is this assumption pretty common for problems like this? For without this assumption, I don't think Postulate $2$ could've been verified.


Any clarifications regarding these two issues will be highly appreciated.

I understand that you are worried to be perfectly rigorous, but your definition fits with the definition of a "standard" discrete probability space ; See here : in this way, there is nothing else to prove ; the "atoms" of your probability space are the events $O_i$...
